# SSH key setup for Joyent Node SmartMachine and Windows?

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-keys, joyent

I just got a Joyent Node SmartMachine.

I'm using Windows.

My goal is to SSH in to the SmartMachine and add/install things from GitHub.

The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to connect to my SmartMachine via SSH using Putty.

In Putty, after I enter my username, I get the message:

> Disconnected, No supported authentication methods available

My guess is that I have not properly setup my SSH keys.

What are the steps in Windows and the Node Control panel to setup the SSH keys?

Answer (score 3):

You can use puttygen to generate your ssh key.
The steps are:

1. Choose "SSH-2 RSA"
2. Click "Generate"
3. Follow the instruction (move mouse randomly)
4. After the key has been successfully generated, paste the string in
   below the "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys
   file:" into the ssh-keys list in your Joyent Node account
5. Save the private key by clicking "Save private key".

Setup your putty with the following settings:

1. Go to smartmachine you wish to connect to.
2. There is line saying "Append this to your $HOME/.ssh/config file"
3. Under that line there is your server host name, your server port and your ssh username (usually "node", without quote). You can put something like, node@.no.de in putty, with  being your smartmachine name
4. After setting all those up, you need to setup private key file use for authentication. Go to "Connection" -> "SSH" -> "Auth"
5. Select the private key file generated by puttygen.